# "unknown source" error when trying to run app from Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

When installing new application from Android studio, the phone cancels the installation showing a notification that it's from unknown sources.

How can I authorize Android Studio app install on my device?

Notice: the device used is vivo y97 (Funtouch OS_9) connected to android studio using USB cable.

Answer (score 1):

for running on real device you should follow these steps first:

Run Android App on Real device

You need to follow these steps to make your Android Device ready so that you can test your App.

Enable Developer Option
Enable USB Debugging
Install USB Drivers
Connect the Device to Computer
Enabling Developer Option

To Enable USB Debugging, First, we need to enable Developer Option on the phone. Google since Android Version 4.2 has disabled the Developer Option. This was done so that people do not enable the USB Debugging Mode accidentally. Enabling USB Debugging Mode puts your device into the security risk.

For the devices with Android Version lower than 4.,2 the developer Option is already enabled.

To Enable the Developer Option to follow the steps

1. Go to settings and tap on About Phone / About Device or About Tablet Option
2. Tap on Software Info Option
3. Locate Build Number and Tap on it seven times. You will see the message “You are now a developer” message. If the developer mode is already enabled then you will see the message “No need, developer mode has already been enabled”

Disable Developer option

In case you wish to disable the developer option you can go to Settings -> Application Manager. Select the Settings App. Select the Storage Option and clear the data. Note this will also reset your preferences within the settings menu.

Enable USB debugging

To enable USB Debugging, follow these steps

Go to Settings
Go to Developer Options
Goto USB Debugging Option and enable it

Disable Developer option

In case you wish to disable the developer option you can go to Settings -> Application Manager. Select the Settings App. Select the Storage Option and clear the data. Note this will also reset your preferences within the settings menu.

Enable USB debugging

To enable USB Debugging, follow these steps

Go to Settings
Go to Developer Options
Goto USB Debugging Option and enable it
Connecting Over Wi-Fi

Connect your device on the same wifi network as that of PC

Find out the IP Address of the Device. There are two ways you can find out the IP address.

Goto settings -> About Device
Tap on Status.
Or

Goto settings -> Wi-Fi
Tap on the Wifi Network connected
Locate the adb.exe. The adb is known as Android Debug Bridge is the tool that lets us communicate with a device. This tool is located under the platform-tools folder under the Android SDK folder.

The Android SDK folder can be found out by type SET ANDROID_HOME command. goto the folder
The adb is already running and listening on the USB port for the devices. To make it to listen to the TCP/IP Port number 5555 run the following command

```
adb tcpip 5555
```

Now, to connect the device run the following command

```
adb connect 192.168.0.103:5555
```

Replace the IP 192.168.0.103 with the IP Address of your device.

To disable TCP/IP and enable the USB, run the command

```
adb usb
```

To Find out the available devices

```
adb devices
```

Comment: Hello thanks for your answering, I've already did all the steps(from developer option to USB debugger...) but my vivo device is always avoiding to install the app after successful connecting with Android studio